# mageInit KO binding not working for a custom jQuery widget

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, jquery, knockoutjs, ui-library

I can't get the [mageInit binding](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#mageinit) to work on a custom jQuery widget which I have created.

I have used it in my KO template like:

```
<div data-bind="mageInit: {'mywidget':{'configuration-value':true}">
```

But in the chrome inspector I can see that it does not load the JS file for my widget.

However, when I try adding a one of [Magento's own jQuery widgets](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/jquery-widgets-about.html) it works.

```
<div data-bind="mageInit: {'accordion':{'collapsible': true}}"></div>
```

Also, I can get my own custom widget to work in a phtml template with...

```
<div data-mage-init='{ "mywidget": {"configuration-value":true} }'>
```

---

I created my jQuery widget by adding the following code.

*Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            mywidget: 'Namespace_Module/js/my-widget'
        }
    }
}
```

*Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/my-widget.js*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    "use strict";

    $.widget('mage.mywidget', {
        _create: function() {
            // Init code
            console.log('test1');
        }
    });

    return $.mage.mywidget;
});
```

In the above piece of code I've used the `mage` namespace, but I've also tried using `holy`. It doesn't make a difference either way and Im unsure which is correct.

---

I have also tried using the full path to my widget in the mageInit binding...

```
<div data-bind="mageInit: {'Namespace_Module/js/my-widget':{'configuration-value':true}">
```

Also I looked at where magento declares the mageInit binding, *vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init.js*, but I can't see why it won't work when I use it for my custom jQuery widget.

---

**UPDATE**

Following the call stack it seems these files are all responsible for initialising components which use the [mageInit binding](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#mageinit).

- lib/web/mage/bootstrap.js ln 20
- lib/web/mage/apply/main.js ln 24 (Initializes components assigned to a specified element via data-* attribute.)
- vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init.js ln 20

Comment: In your code of KO bindings, you are missing a `}`. `"mageInit: {'mywidget':{'configuration-value':true}"` should be `"mageInit: {'mywidget':{'configuration-value':true}}"`